# config Spring scheduled task to start after user authentication

Tags: java, spring, websocket, scheduled-tasks

i have an issue with spring Scheduled methode that start when i deployed my project ,so i was wonding if there is a methode that can start the Scheduled task after user authentification

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay=10000, fixedRate = 5000)
    public void sendGpsData() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("sendGpsData");
        this.template.convertAndSend("/gps-data/send", new Greeting("send me noodles"));
    }
```

note that i'm using socket to send data every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically schedule the job when the user authenticates. So somewhere in your handling of user authentication, you'd start the scheduling. Remove the `@Scheduled` annotation from your `sendGpsData` method, and then when the user authenticates do:

```
TaskScheduler scheduler = // injected by spring;
ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduler.schedule(() -> sendGpsData(), new PeriodicTrigger(5000));

// You can later unschedule the job if you'd like to by doing
scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
```

Comment: thank you @Brian it work now, but i'm no longer receiving data from socket

Answer (score 0):

so i want to share my solution , but before here is some detail about the problem that i have faced,i have a map that i want to send gps coordiante every 2 seconds so i used spring websocket for that in my controller i injected like @Brian Ecker said

```
@Autowired
private TaskScheduler scheduler;
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;
```

and int methode that show the map i started the scheduled task

```
   @RequestMapping(value = {"/tracking"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView trackingPage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("track/tracking");
        User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduler.schedule(() -> sendGpsData(user), new PeriodicTrigger(2000));
        return model;
    }
```

and here the methode that send data to socket

```
 public void sendGpsData(User user) {
        System.out.println(user.getUsername());
        this.template.convertAndSendToUser(user.getUsername(), "/gps-data/send", user);
    }
```